# Hook the language switcher and change the URLs it redirects to in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a multilanguage site in Drupal 7.

The language negotiation is based on URL. I have got translated content, so when I visit **www.example.com/this-is-a-news** in *English*, I can change to *Spanish* using the **language switcher** and go to **www.example.com/esta-es-una-noticia**, which is the URL of the translated node. However, I have some URLs which are dynamic, i.e., they are built in-the-fly, for example: www.example.com/this-is-a-news/on-the-fly-parameter...

As the part of the URL */on-the-fly-parameter* is completely dynamic and can change, and because the translation is a non-Drupal table in the database which is updated independently, I want to hook the language switcher and add the translations of all of these URLs dynamically. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered how to do it.

```
function MYTEMPLATE_language_switch_links_alter(array &$links, $type, $path) {


 $extract_parameters_URL = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

 $code_altered_url = process_URL_extracts($extract_parameters_URL);

 foreach ($links as $langcode => $link) {

    $links[$langcode]['href'] = $code_altered_url ;

 } // foreach
```

Comment: It seems you've two accounts on DA. So you can merge them. Check it out [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)